# cant execute perl script - Strange error

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a perl script which running fine in my system but not working in some other system.

It is showing error **"can't execute ...... at line 1**". 
everything is set up. I have tested in version 5.8.2 and working fine. But in 5.8.6 it is not working. While compile this code **I got that Archive/Tar.pm is missing**.

I have checked in my system perl lib folder there is no such Folder/module. Also I didnt get any result for **perldoc -lm Archive::Tar** in my system but still it is running fine.

Can you let me know what might be the possible problem ?

**First line :: #! C:\system\Perl**

**This program is for windows**

Comment: The perl interpreters location is correct in the first line? For example if your first line looks like `#! /usr/bin/perl`, is the interpreter there?

Comment: this is script for windows.

Comment: This first line is suspicious anyway. Is the interpreter this: C:\system\Perl ?

Comment: @rajarshi it doesn't matter. #!/usr/bin/perl works on Windows

Comment: I am confused why it is saying that Archive/Tar.pm is missing ? or Cant execute .... line 1. for other systems

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: perl script_name.
Note: this is working in my system

Comment: You don't tell us how you transfered this between systems. Perhaps you've messed up the line endings and can't find the perl interpreter. Use a sensible text editor like Notepad++ to ensure that line endings are correct.

    #!/usr/bin/perl 

Is a valid shebang line on Windows.

Comment: see it is .pl script and in windows I can easily copy paste a file and run

Comment: @rajarshi you post no code, you don't even post the full error. Make some effort

Comment: I cannot post actual code here as they are in my office system. I dont feel there is any problem with my script. I didnt get why it is saying cann't locate Archive/Tar.pm in @INC. I have compare lib folder both my system and other system, there is no such folder/module for Archive, but still it is running in my system and not running with other system. even if I run perl -c script, in my system I getting Debug OK, but other system is showing the above error "cann't locate Archive/Tar.pm in @INC";

Comment: @rajarshi: Just install `Archive::Tar`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running dos2unix on your script. It probably has Carriage Returns in the first line.

```
dos2unix yourscript
```

You can check with

```
cat -vet yourscript
```

CR shows up as ^M.

Also, try running:

```
which perl
```

and make sure that your first line matches the answer.

Try running the script using:

```
perl yourscript
```

rather than

```
./yourscript
```

Comment: this script is for windows

Comment: This solved my problem on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the first line is terminated correctly for your OS (for example, Linux hates CR+LF line terminators... :-)

Comment: this is script for windows and it is running fine in my system, but not is other systems

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is saying that `Archive::Tar` is missing then it is probably right. Don't argue with it - just install the module.